# Sending HTMLVideoElement with chrome.runtime.sendMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, video, google-chrome-extension

I'm pretty new to chrome extension development, I'm trying to make a better PiP (Picture in Picture) that doesn't have the maximum window size limitation.

I'm using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-pip-vi/eaeedemddlledlghhjebjgdmhjekgegd/related?hl=en) as reference, it basically behaves the same way as the default PiP works with `video.requestPictureInPicture()` which is what I don't want to use because extension popup has limited window size.

Instead, I have a `index.html` page with my extension that is loaded with `window.open` in `background.js`, this index page will have a video element that the HTMLVideoElement is passed to.

I've tried using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send the video to the video.js that the index.html page loads, but this doesn't seem to work with a `HTMLVideoElement`? I read elsewhere that I should do JSON.stringify/JSON.parse for this object but that results in undefined.

Relevant manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [{ 
    "resources": [ "index.html" ],
    "matches": [ "*://*/*" ]
}],
"manifest_version": 3,
"permissions": [ "storage", "scripting", "activeTab", "tabs" ],
```

content.js:

```
const videos = new Set();

window.addEventListener('canplay', e => {
    if(e.target.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
        videos.add(e.target);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            method: 'VIDEO_PLAYING'
        });
    }
}, true);
```

background.js:

```
await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
...

    var win = window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html'), 'PiP');
    win.focus();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: 'VIDEO',
        data: JSON.stringify(video)
    });
```

video.js: - this is the js that is just included on index.html

```
const onMessage = (request, sender) => {
    if(request.method === 'VIDEO') {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.data);
        console.log(video.src); //undefined
    }
};
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessage);
```

Maybe my method of going about doing this is entirely wrong. Are there other ways I can pass such objects to index.html like this?

Comment: You can't send a DOM element to a cross-origin window so this won't work.

Comment: I should clarify that the window is opened from within `chrome.scripting.executeScript` on background.js does this behave similar to an iframe? It's not an iframe itself, it's index.html in the extensions root directory where the url is retrieved with `chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html')`

Comment: The function you inject is a content script running in the web page so any extension window/page/frame is cross-origin to it.

Comment: So it's not possible to access page elements from an opened window originating from the injected content script at all?

Comment: No, because the content script runs in the web page origin.